# Kivy window freezes from matplotlib graph even after using threading and multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, user-interface, kivy

Right now I am just trying to make a proof of concept for a future project with Kivy.  I want to have an application where when you click on a button a certain task occurs which sends you to a new screen and displays some real-time graphs.  However, my Kivy window keeps freezing while plotting these figures and never actually transitions to the next screen.  I am not a wiz when it comes to Kivy or Python in general.  I assumed that utilizing threading or a queue would stop the window freezing like in Tkinter.  Alas, I was incorrect.  Everything I try still results in the window freezing up and crashing.  Below is my .py code block and my .kv file.

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def button_log(self,button):
        #button = self.children[-1]
        button_text = button.text
        global button_log
        button_log.append(button_text)
        return button_text, button_log


class LinePlotScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class GraphWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(GraphWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.fig , self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([],[])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(self.fig)
        GraphWidget().add_widget(self.canvas)

        self.x_data = []
        self.y_data = []

        self.is_running = False

    def start_update(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self.is_running = True
            self.queue = Queue()
            self.process = Process(target=self.update_graph_process,args=(self.queue,))
            self.process.start()
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_graph, 0.1)

    def stop_update(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.process.terminate()

    def update_graph_process(self,queue):
        while self.is_running:
            x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
            y = np.sin(x)
            queue.put((x,y))
            plt.pause(0.001)

    def update_graph(self, dt):


        #x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
        #y = np.sin(x)
        if not self.queue.empty():
            x, y = self.queue.get()

            self.x_data.append(x)
            self.y_data.append(y)
            #self.ax.cla()

            self.line.set_data(self.x_data,self.y_data)
            self.ax.relim()
            self.ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
            self.canvas.draw

kv = Builder.load_file('Simplified.kv')
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):

        self.stop_value = 0
        self.data_int = None
        self.left_shoe = []
        self.right_shoe = []

        return kv



    def on_button_press(self):
        global button_log
        if button_log[-1] == 'Start Data Collection':
            UDP_IP = "192.168.1.100"
            UDP_PORT = 3333
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), UDP_PORT))
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                self.data_int = fmt_str(data)
                if self.data_int[0] == 1:
                    self.left_shoe.append(self.data_int)
                elif self.data_int[0] == 2:
                    self.right_shoe.append(self.data_int)
                if self.stop_value == 1:
                    break

        elif button_log[-1] == 'Stop Data Collection':
            self.stop_value = 1
        elif button_log[-1] == 'Plot Line Charts':

            graph = GraphWidget()
            threading.Thread(target=graph.start_update).start()
            LinePlotScreen.ids.box.add_widget(graph)
```

.kv file

```
WindowManager:
    HomeScreen:
    LinePlotScreen:

<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width,root.height

        Label:
            text: 'Home'
            font_size: 32

        Button:
            id: Start
            text: 'Start Data Collection'
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            size_hint: (0.5,1)
            valign: 'center'
            on_press: root.button_log(self)
            on_release: app.on_button_press()

        Button:
            id: Stop
            text: 'Stop Data Collection'
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            size_hint: (0.5,1)
            valign: 'center'
            on_press: root.button_log(self)
            on_release: app.on_button_press()

        Button:
            id: plot_line
            text: 'Plot Line Charts'
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            size_hint: (0.5,1)
            valign: 'center'
            on_press:
                root.button_log(self)
                app.on_button_press()
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'lineplot'

<LinePlotScreen>:
    name: 'lineplot'
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width,root.height

        Label:
            text: 'Line Graphs'
            font_size: 32
```

Here is another rendition of code where I only use threading and no multiprocessing.

```
class GraphWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(GraphWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.fig , self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([],[])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(self.fig)
        GraphWidget().add_widget(self.canvas)

        self.x_data = []
        self.y_data = []

        self.is_running = False

    def start_update(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self.is_running = True
            #self.queue = Queue()
            #self.process = Process(target=self.update_graph_process,args=(self.queue,))
            #self.process.start()
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_graph)
            self.thread.daemon = True
            self.thread.start()
            #Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_graph, 0.1)

    def stop_update(self):
        if self.is_running():
            self.is_running = False
            self.thread.join()
    def update_graph(self):
        #if not self.queue.empty():
        while self.is_running:
            #x, y = self.queue.get()
            x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
            y = np.sin(x)

            self.x_data.append(x)
            self.y_data.append(y)
            #self.ax.cla()

            self.line.set_data(self.x_data,self.y_data)
            self.ax.relim()
            self.ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
            self.canvas.draw
            plt.pause(0.001)
```

From my experience with Tkinter, I expected this freezing issue to occur at some point.  However, I thought it would be a simple fix by just using threading.Thread(target).start().  This fix didn't do a thing though.  I then started looking around and found some talking about queues and multiprocessing.  I tried implementing this but to no avail.  I then tried combining the two methods (I know that sounds dumb, but I've been working on this bug for the past couple of days).  I am now finally turning to making my own Stack Overflow post.  There is a good possibility I am just implementing one of these fixes wrong.  I have been on a time crunch for this project so I spent just a couple of days on learning how to use Kivy.  Thank you to anyone who can help me out.